# Coursera Neural Nets

Tags: machine-learning

If I go to https://www.coursera.org/course/neuralnets

and click preview, there are many video lectures. Does anyone know if these are the same lectures you see if you enroll in a course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are exactly the same. The only difference is you don't have access to extra materials like slides or extra pdf with more informations